# How to right create url?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have page, from which I call two query. This two query need id.
How can I pass this id in the URL?
For example I call book and author query.
I pass them in URL,

`mysite.com/book/:id/author/:id`
`mysite.com/:id/:id`

Which option would be better? or is there another better way?

Comment: Why not `mysite.com/book/:bookID/author/:authorID`?

Comment: you cant have two variables with the same name. how you are planning to manage that?

Comment: First one will be more explainatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one should be readable.
`mysite.com/book/:id/author/:id`

> But I prefer using slug. Example below.

`mysite.com/book-slug/author-slug`

Then in your back end, just remove `book-` and `author-` to get their slug.
This way you can reduce the number of parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

why not request author by id after you already get a book?
eg:

mysite.com/book/:id?bookeId=123

Comment: Your idea looks reasonable.
Where can I read about it? How right to make links?

Comment: For example, how will I do this?
`mysite.com/page?authorId=1,bookeId=2`

I can send one argument.
`/page?{authorId:int}`


But the second does not work
`/page?{authorId:int, bookId:int}`

Comment: @0xD34F that's not how you add the query parameters, it should be `mysite.com/page?authorId=1&bookeId=2`. It's your decision to use query or path parameters. But if you are using `Express` or anything for API development pathparameters are handier.